# Oreo phone call broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app that has to listen for phone calls being made by the user, in order to trigger the sending of a notification after each phone call.

This was implemented using a BroadcastReceiver, which would listen for user phone calls, and send the required notification.

I recently found out that Android recently introduced [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html), and found out that my app doesn't work anymore.

Does the Android community have any suggestions on exactly how to implement such a feature in Android > 8 ?

Comment: What doesn't work? BroasdcastReceiver or Service? Show exceptions which you have got

Comment: I don't get any exceptions. The CallStateBroadcastReceiver simply doesn't fire anymore upon calls on Android Oreo

Comment: Oreo have some restriction in Broadcast Receiver. check this blog link https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c

Answer (score 0):

Apps can register for explicit broadcasts in their manifests.